# Accept only special characters in Selection Screen parameter

Tags: special-characters, abap, sap-selection-screens

I have one input field of type C.

```
PARAMETERS lv_sep TYPE c.
```

Field lv_sep should accept only special characters.

Can you help me how i can give this constraint?

Comment: In order to distinguish parameters from data values, one usually names parameters as p_* , so in this case it ought to be p_sep. Furthermore not mentioning length, because the default is one and not using a custom type is very old skool, and ought to be avoided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do checks during AT-SELECTION-SCREEN. You could for instance check the parameter lv_sep for the characters you want to accept.

```
AT-SELECTION-SCREEN.
if not lv_sep CO '!"§$%&/()=?'.
    message text-e01 type E.
endif.
```

Answer (score 2):

Because I like to avoid NOT in IF statements when I can, I would propose this:

```
AT-SELECTION-SCREEN.
IF lv_sep CN '!"§$%&/()=?'.
  MESSAGE text-e01 TYPE E.
ENDIF.
```